# how can i select one row from table in MySQL database alone in anthor page with php?

Tags: php, mysql, web, phpmyadmin, web-deployment

i create questions and answers system with php and i created page have all questions that recorded in table named questions and make beside every question reply link which directed to answer page, so i need to select this question that i want to comment on it from table and show it single in the answer page to make comments on it , how can i make this with php?

this is my questions page code

```
<?php  session_start();  $connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','','questionssystem') or die ("Database connection failed"); /*start questions*/$sql = "SELECT question_text FROM question"; $result = $connection->query($sql); echo'<h2>Questions page</h2>'; if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<form action="answers.php" method="post">';
    echo '<div class ="container">';
    echo "<p>question: " . $row["question_text"];
    echo '<span class="psw">If You want to reply this Question , please <a href="http://localhost:8080/questionssystem/answers.php" target="_self">Reply</a></span>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</form>'; } }else { echo "0 results";} /*end questions*/ $connection->close(); ?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_file.css">
</head>
<body></body></html>
```

Comment: okay you want user to click on reply and redirect them to answer on clicked question ?

Comment: then check my post please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading you question i guess you want to provide a link "Reply" on question , so on redirect user can answer to that question,

you can do is send question ID from database in GET to other page

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/questionssystem/answers.php?questionID=12" target="_self">Reply</a>
```

on answer page

```
$QID = $_GET['questionID'];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: when i put $QID = $_GET['questionID']; in answer page give me on browser Notice: Undefined index: questionID in C:\xampp\htdocs\questionsystem\answers.php on line 5

Comment: are you sending questionID in url ?

Comment: please share your new code, and i will look tommorow in it , due to my work i cant reply now sorry.

Comment: echo '<div class ="container">';
        echo "<p>question: " . $row["question_text"];
        echo '<span class="psw">If You want to reply this Question , please <a href="http://localhost:8080/stackoverflow/answers.php?questionID=12" target="_self">Reply</a></span>';
        echo '</div>';

Comment: answer.php page  <?php 
 $connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','','stackoverflow') or die ("Database connection failed");

$QID = $_GET['questionID'];
?>

Comment: foreign key is next question, but first you need to get value of question Id on answers.php page

Answer (score 0):

Using Foreign Key - One column which links two different SQL tables!

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp